# Truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous

Tags: python, numpy

I was given this question and I'm not sure why I'm getting an error with my code.

> Question 4. Suppose there were 30,000 beachgoers in 1930 and the
>   number of beachgoers increased by 15% year-after-year. Create an array
>   called beachgoers that contains the number of beachgoers in each year
>   between 1930 and 2017. If any beachgoer is equally likely to be
>   attacked by a shark, how dangerous was the least dangerous year for
>   shark attacks? Assign the percent chance of being attacked by a shark
>   to the variable danger. Hint: To calculate beachgoers, you may find
>   the function np.arange helpful.

```
yearly_growth_rate =  30000 * 1.15 ** np.arange(1, 88) - 30000
final_number = 30000 * (1.15 ** 88)
beachgoers = np.arange(30000, final_number, yearly_growth_rate)
beachgoers
#danger = ...
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-df37b4a34579> in <module>()
      1 yearly_growth_rate =  30000 * 1.15 ** np.arange(1, 88) - 30000
      2 final_number = 30000 * (1.15 ** 88)
----> 3 beachgoers = np.arange(30000, final_number, yearly_growth_rate)
      4 beachgoers
      5 #danger = ...

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: I think this answers the question, right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Comment: I can't see where I'm evaluating the array in a boolean context though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just

```
30000 * (1.15 ** np.arange(0, 88))
```

which will translate to

```
[30000 * (1.15 ** 0),
 30000 * (1.15 ** 1),
 30000 * (1.15 ** 2),
 ...]
```

The last argument of [`np.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) is the step, which should be a number. It makes no sense to pass an array as argument.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your `yearly_growth_rate` is an array, rather than an `int`. The `numpy.arange()` function takes four params:

`start` = Optional `int` type
 `stop` = Required place to stop
 `step-size` = Optional size between elements (`int`)
 `dtype` = optional output type of `arange`

Check the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) for help

Answer (score 0):

The third parameter for `np.arange` [is a number](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and you're providing an array. It's possible that the implementation of `np.arrange` uses the truth value of the parameter to check that it's not either `None` or zero.